# Can you use a ViewComponent in a Blazor layout?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

Just trying Blazor out for the first time. With the default Blazor template, I added a `ViewComponent` call to the `MainLayout.cshtml`:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("HeaderComponent")
```

IntelliSense shows `await` can only be used in an `async` method.

I tried the same in a Blazor view—same result. I use the component in an MVC app in the layout (via `<vc:header-component />`).

So I'm not sure if this is possible, or just a current Blazor or Visual Studio 2019 limitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't use ViewComponent in Blazor. And yes, this is a limitation, in the same sense you can't use ViewComponent in Angular.

Why do you need a partial view ? Is there any use case in Blazor that components  cannot satisfy ?

Comment: The reason was I'm looking at migrating an MVC app to Blazor (seems like a good test).  I like the ViewComponent handling all related stuff for display & the providing the model.  But yes I guess Blazor will do it fine in its own way.  Just getting used to what it does.  Thanks for the clarification.